# Can a user change kernel configuration form within a docker container?

Tags: security, docker, linux-kernel, containers

According to what I understood from reading docker's documentation, containers share the kernel of the host on which they run. Does that mean that a user can - by using a container - set the kernel configuration as he will? Be cause if that is the case why would we bother to allow/deny Kernel capabilities if the user can set kernel itself? My third question is : if indeed users can set the kernel, can't systems like Apparmor help prevent that from happening?

To summarize here are my questions :

1. Can users change a docker host's kernel configuration from within a running container (since they share the kernel)?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, then why bother to limit the containers' kernel capabilities?
3. Still if the answer to 1 is yes, can system like Apparmor (One of the solution given in [this entry of docker's security documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#other-kernel-security-features) that can supposedly harden the security of docker host's kernel) prevent such an attack?

Answer (score 1):

> Can users change a docker host's kernel configuration from within a
>   running container (since they share the kernel)

A container runs in its own sandbox. It has it own filesystem that is isolated from the host. Thus by default it doesn't have access to affect the host and its kernel.

Now you can give the container access to critical stuff by mounting  host directories that are only accessible by a root admin user. And since by default a `root` inside the container will
be `root` outside the container, then it is possible to exploit critical stuff on the machine from mounted directories. This however was solved using [user namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/).

Thus as long as you don't give the container access to crtical stuff, it is still quiet secure even more secure than running the application directly on the host.

You can read more on docker security in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to prevent docker from mounting these type of volumes? In other words disable the "bind mounts" functionnality. We put a VM at the disposal of our clients pre-equipped with control programs. What we fear is that if we let them use docker they might use the containers to effectively stop those programs.

Comment: Directory mounts are not automatic, they are created when running `docker run -v <host-dir>:<container-dir> ...`. So you can restict which users can start containers or better enable usernamespace. Once you enable username spaces mounting critical directories will be safe.